# New version of Google Maps SDK in the Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps

I am using Google Maps in my Flutter app, but when I launch page where map is implemented, I get this warning in the console

[image: Warning in console]

I tried to reinstall this SDK using `pod`, but nothing work. I even tried to manually update `podfile` in my project and then run commands to install it, but I got another errors.
I also tried follow this tutorial - https://medium.com/flutter/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245, but it does not work either.

Do you have any experiences with this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately